# Split-View Based Application - Navigation in RootViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

*Solved*
Hey all,

I'm currently working on a Split-View Based Application for iPad. I want the Root View Controller to navigate to another TableView, and from there, the users can select the appropriate row and display the information in the DetailViewController. I managed to code the navigation part in (The Root View Controller navigates to another table instead of displaying information instantly to the Detail View Controller), but I can't seem to display information based on the user's TableView selection.

The Hierarchy of Selection is as follows:
RootViewController -->Select Row in Root View Controller --->Navigate to TableView-->Select Row from TableView-->Display in Detail View Controller

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was my solution, partly.

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath (delegate is my app delegate singleton):

```
[delegate setDetailItem:newFile];
```

setDetailItem:

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{

    if (detailItem != newDetailItem)
    {
        [detailItem release];
        detailItem = [newDetailItem retain];
    }
    detailViewController.detailItem = self.detailItem;


        [self.detailViewController configureView];
    }
```

the detailViewController has an (id) variable `detailItem` which i set from the row i selected. then i configure my detailview as needed based on this item. So there is a start for you.